# GWT/GWT-RPC using com.google.gdata.contacts

Tags: java, gdata-api, gwt-rpc, gdata

I am putting together a tutorial showing how combine GWT, RPC and the gData API using Java

I would like to utilize the existing gdata contacts classes (from gdata-contacts-3.0.jar et.al.) with the client-side logic, but have not figured out how I can inherit the gdata classes -- there does not appear to be a gxt.xml configuration which would allow the gData classes to be used a GWT modules.

The only way I can think of accomplishing this is to extract the information I need using the gdata API in the server-side logic and repackage the information into String fields within a custom class that I can pass to and from the client using GWT-RPC.

Yuk! -- this feels like I am needlessly reinventing the wheel...

... advice appreciated, as I am trying to show how easy it is to leverage the existing APIs.

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.insideit.fr/post/2009/02/09/Leveraging-Google-Data-APIs-Java-client-library-with-GWT